# See all DML changes in Oracle session before committing

Tags: java, oracle, spring-transactions

I'm writing a test harness for an Oracle (10g) stored procedure. I'm planning to use a `@Transactional` test to run the stored procedure, so that the transaction will be rolled back when the test ends. So my test looks like:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:spring/ITestAssembly.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ContentGenerationRunnerTest {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void contentIncShouldRun() throws Exception {
        new ContentGenerationRunner().runVclBec(jdbcTemplate);
    }
}
```

I can assert that the correct updates have been made, since the changes local to the test's session will be visible within the test method.

However to make more strict assertions, it'd be handy to be able to check for a complete list of DML statements that have been called in the session, but not yet committed. Is there a way I can see this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related question:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2994/oracle-any-way-to-view-uncommited-changes-to-a-particular-table